# CSS Use Grid and Flex at the same time

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. CSS isn't my favorite part of coding and I can't figure this out. I need the following result:
[image]

But here is what I have now:

```css
#newOrderControl {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: min-content;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#newOrderInputFields {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    column-gap: 40px;
}

#newOrderInputFields .inputField {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#newOrderInputFields label {
    width: auto;
}




#newOrderButtons button {
    float: right;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0px 5px;
}

.btnAll {
    background-color: #6DA0ED;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#btnTakeProfit {
    background-color: #33AB37;
}

#btnPlaceOrder {
    background-color: #6DA0ED;
}

.title {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1D0F73;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="newOrderControl">
    <label class="title">New order</label>
    <div id="newOrderInputFields">
        <div class="inputField">
            <label>Action:</label>
            <select id="txtOrderAction">
                <option value="">-</option>
                <option value="Buy">Buy</option>
                <option value="Sell">Sell</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
            <label>Quantity:</label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="txtOrderQuantity">
                <button class="btnAll" onclick="setAllQuantity()">All</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
            <label>Target price:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtOrderTargetPrice">
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
            <label>Target perc:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtOrderTargetPerc">
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
            <label>Coin:</label>
            <select id="txtOrderCoin">
                <option value="">-</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
            <label>Amount:</label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="txtOrderAmount">
                <button class="btnAll" onclick="setAllAmount()">All</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
            <label>Limit price:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtOrderLimitPrice">
        </div>
        <div class="inputField">
            <label>Limit perc:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtOrderLimitPerc">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="newOrderButtons">
        <button id="btnTakeProfit">Take profit</button>
        <button id="btnPlaceOrder">Place order</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this code I currently have the following problems:

- My `All` button isn't next to the input field
- The 2 buttons below are outside the `newOrderControl` `div`
- The `labels` are being wrapped to the next line
- All inputs and labels need to be aligned below each other like a grid

Now I have tried to change it to a `grid`, but then I was struggling with the `input` and `button` that are next to each other. So I wrapped them in a `div`, but then they completely disappear.

What do I need to do to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Removing the wrapper `<div>` in below code will automatically align the input and buttons by the power of flexbox.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="txtOrderQuantity">
    <button class="btnAll" onclick="setAllQuantity()">All</button>
</div>
```

---

(2) First rule: **do not** use `float` for layout.

I've added:

```
#newOrderControl {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
```

So that buttons can be aligned to the right with

```
#newOrderInputFields label {
  width: auto;
}
```

---

(3) Applying `flex-shrink: 0;` will prevent the `<label>` from wrapping. I've changed the `width` of container to `width: max-content;` and reduced `gap` to compensate for it.

---

(4) added `justify-content: flex-end;` to align them:

```
#newOrderInputFields .inputField {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
```

```css
#newOrderControl {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: max-content;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#newOrderInputFields {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  column-gap: 5px;
}

#newOrderInputFields .inputField {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

#newOrderInputFields label {
  width: auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

#newOrderButtons {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#newOrderButtons button {
  float: right;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}

.btnAll {
  background-color: #6DA0ED;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#btnTakeProfit {
  background-color: #33AB37;
}

#btnPlaceOrder {
  background-color: #6DA0ED;
}

.title {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #1D0F73;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="newOrderControl">
  <label class="title">New order</label>
  <div id="newOrderInputFields">
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Action:</label>
      <select id="txtOrderAction">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="Buy">Buy</option>
        <option value="Sell">Sell</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Quantity:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderQuantity">
      <button class="btnAll" onclick="setAllQuantity()">All</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Target price:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderTargetPrice">
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Target perc:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderTargetPerc">
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Coin:</label>
      <select id="txtOrderCoin">
        <option value="">-</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Amount:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderAmount">
      <button class="btnAll" onclick="setAllAmount()">All</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Limit price:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderLimitPrice">
    </div>
    <div class="inputField">
      <label>Limit perc:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrderLimitPerc">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="newOrderButtons">
    <button id="btnTakeProfit">Take profit</button>
    <button id="btnPlaceOrder">Place order</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, the buttons are next to each other now! How can I prevent the label to go to the next row? And the Action and coin input are not aligned below each other. They start/stop on different points

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk `flex-shrink: 0;`

Comment: But then the last input fileds go outside the div border?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk there is simply not enough space for everything, you want to increase the container size or decrease the size of something else, like inputs?

Comment: Okay, hold up. I will update my code with what I have now!

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk I've changed the width to `max-content` and reduced the `gap`

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk please don't change the question completely, that invalidates the effort from people who was answering the question.If you have a new specific problem please ask a new question. Also check the updated answer, I think it pretty much covers every problem mentioned in original question

Comment: But this problem was in my list with problems at the top